# Verbosity of conda install output

Tags: anaconda, conda, verbosity

I recently reinstalled Anaconda. Now, the output is extremely verbose. Eg, when it's downloading the packages, it tells me where it's looking (see picture); when it finished, it gave me a long list of something I didn't understand.

> [link to picture because I need 10 rep to post picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2EIb.png)
>
> [link to another picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iXpg.png)

I used not to have all these `DEBUG` lines, and I would prefer not to have them again.

I tested the `verbosity`, but it's already set to the lowest level, `0`. I tested changing it to `3`, just in case I misunderstood the order of importance, but `3` was more verbose.

```
conda config --describe verbosity
# # verbosity (int)
# #   aliases: verbose
# #   Sets output log level. 0 is warn. 1 is info. 2 is debug. 3 is trace.
# #
# verbosity: 0
```

I tried this both in `Powershell Prompt` and `(Console) Prompt`.